# LibGDX Box2D gravity is being slow even after pixels/meter conversion

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am doing a test project to learn box2d and I am having an issue. The circle body in my simulation is falling veerrry slowly. I did all the pixel/meter conversions as shown in this video: https://youtu.be/IDZMRDb1A_M?t=13m35s (Set to part of tutorial covering this subject). Here is my code:

```
public static final float PPM = 32;//Pixels per meter

private World world;
private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;

private OrthographicCamera box2DCamera;

@Override
public void create() {
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.81f), true);
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    //Create test platform
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.position.set(100 / PPM, 200 / PPM);
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;

    Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(32 / PPM);

    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    fdef.shape = shape;
    body.createFixture(fdef);

    box2DCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
    box2DCamera.setToOrtho(false, Metroid.WIDTH / PPM, Metroid.HEIGHT / PPM);
    box2DCamera.translate(Metroid.WIDTH / 2 / PPM, Metroid.HEIGHT / 2 / PPM);
}

@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {
    world.step(deltaTime, 6, 2);
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    debugRenderer.render(world, box2DCamera.combined);
}
```

It's very basic and I have absolutely no idea what is wrong. Thanks in advance :)

EDIT (Extra details from testing): After some testing, I have found that even changing the steptime of the world.step call to 2000, it is still very slow, a bit faster, but still really slow. And trust me it is being called, I tested it.

Comment: is slower than the video?

Comment: Much slower. It's so slow that I needed to place a post-it on my screen to mark the original position of the circle and then come back later to see if it moved at all. It did but not by much.

Comment: maybe making your body more dense `fdef.density = 2.0f.`? what's the size of `Metroid.WIDTH` and `Metroid.HEIGHT`?

Comment: lol. I called the project Metroid. They are just the viewport widths and heights. I tried changing the density. Even changing it to 400 doesn't do anything noticeable. By the way, I added more details in my question.

Comment: I figured it out. Stupid me, I made a mistake in my other parts of my code that called the create() method every frame, resetting all bodies and the world. Thank for your help.